# Segmentation Fault with c pointer

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have a segmentation fault with the following code and i really don't understand where the issue is...

```
int *p;
p[0]=1;
printf("%d\n",*p);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

`p` is uninitialized. `p[0]` (equivalent to `*(p + 0)`, which is effectively `*p`) attempts to dereference it, which results in undefined behavior due to the indeterminate value in `p`.

To make the program well-defined you need to make it point to some allocated memory location:

```
int i;
int* p = &i;

p[0] = 1;

printf("%d\n", *p);
```

Answer (score 2):

`p` is not initialized. You need to initialize it first before dereferencing, otherwise it will lead to undefined behavior.

```
int *p;   // p is pointing to a random location in memory
int a;
p = &a;   // p is pointing to the variable a
p[0] = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int *p;
```

`p` is an uninitialized pointer and may point to any unauthorized memory and with the below statement you tend to write to some invalid memory -

```
p[0]=1;
```

You can allocate memory to do so -

```
int *p=malloc(sizeof(int));
if(p!=NULL){
   p[0]=1; 
   printf("%d",p[0]);
}
free(p);
```